# GROUP BY in a temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

I'm working on a stored procedure and altering a temp table to spit out data depending on a specific condition. This stored procedure is quite complex and has like 40 columns, however for this specific issue I simply need to group the records by the `DESCR` column. The other 37 columns all have the same value so it shouldn't be an issue but in this case how can I group them by their `DESCR` and consolidate the `LATEFEE` and `CHG` values?

The query essentially looks like this:

```sql
SELECT [columns1], [column38], t.descr t.chg, t.lateFee, (t.chg + t.lateFee) as Total
FROM #tmpStatement t
    INNER JOIN dbo.Association a ON t.AssocID = a.AssocID
    INNER JOIN dbo.Company c ON a.CompanyID = c.CompanyID
GROUP BY
  [all columns]
```

If I remove the `t.chg` or the `t.lateFee` columns from the `GROUP BY` clause then SQL tells me that they are invalid in the `SELECT` list since they're not included in the `GROUP BY`, however I still want those values in my table.

Currently this is the outcome of the table:

```
DESCR      CHG   LATEFEE    TOTAL
=================================
Assessment  1       0         1
Spec        0       2         2
Spec        3       0         3
Assessment  0       5         5
Res         3       0         3
```

What I want the expected result to look like:

```
DESCR      CHG   LATEFEE    TOTAL
=================================
Assessment  1       5         6
Spec        3       2         5
Res         3       0         3
```

Comment: You are looking for `SUM` it seems. You aggregate your data by grouping by the other columns, and you want the CHG sum, the LATEFEE sum and the sum of CHG + LATEFEE. The aggregate function for sums is `SUM`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Technically not consolidate them, but I guess I could add them together. If one row `SPEC` has a late fee of `0` and another row of `SPEC` has a late fee of `2` then I want a the one row of `SPEC` to have a late fee of `2`.

Comment: Pro tip. Read up on [GROUP BY and aggregate functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?source=recommendations&view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: Cross-site dupe: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/323279/1186 (Please just pick one site to post a question.)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the sample data, you probably need something as simple as:

```
select descr, other, sum(chg) as chg, sum(latefee) as latefee, sum(chg) + sum(latefee) as total
from t
group by descr, other
```